# Scrollpane gets disappeared when frame is maximized

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jbutton, actionlistener

My prob is this....

```
JFrame ActualFrame = new JFrame("Actual frame");
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(new JTable(data, columns));
ActualFrame.add(pane);
ActualFrame.add(PrintPreviewBtn);

PrintPreviewBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {            
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   JFrame PreviewFrame = new JFrame("Preview");
   PreviewFrame.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

When i run the program everything seems to b fine but when i press print preview button the preview frame shows off and when i maximize or resize the ActualFrame the table gets disappeared....

NOTE:
I m adding the pane to the preview frame to show as if it is a preview of the table displayed.....is ter any other method for print preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component can only belong to a single parent.  When you add it to the `PreviewFrame`, it is been removed, automatically, from the `ActualFrame`.

Instead of using the previous panel, create a new `JTable`, using the model from the previous one.

**Update**

Printing tables is a little more complicated, as includes the headers, and the columns need to be resized to meet the requirements of the available space.

Take a look at the [Printing Tables tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#printing) for some examples

Answer (score 1):

For printing there is the java.awt.PrinterJob class. To show the standart print preview you should call:

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.printDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Reason for disappearance of JScrollPane from the `ActualFrame` is that: You are adding the same instance of `pane` in `PreviewFrame`. So the actual container of the `pane` is now `PreviewFrame` instead of `ActualFrame`. When you maximize or resize the `ActualFrame`,it repaint its child components. Since the `pane` now no longer belongs to the `ActualFrame` it does not show the `pane` now.

The best way to avoid this situation is to create a seperate `JTabel` instance first, instead of passing anonymous `JTable` class object within the constructor of `JScrollPane` while creating the object `pane` . Get the `TableModel` and `TableColumnModel` of that `JTable` instance. In `previewFrame` add a new instance of `JScrollPane` that will contain the new instance of `JTable` with same `TableModel` and `TableColumnModel` objects.
The Code would look something like this:

```
final JTable table = new JTable(data,columns);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
ActualFrame.add(pane);
ActualFrame.add(PrintPreviewBtn);

PrintPreviewBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {            
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   JFrame previewFrame = new JFrame("Preview");
   javax.swing.table.TableModel tabModel = table.getModel();
   javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel colModel = table.getColumnModel();
   JScrollPane previewPane = new JScrollPane(new JTable(tabModel,colModel));
   previewFrame.getContentPane().add(previewPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   previewFrame.pack();previewFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: @Mad programmer - thank u 4 ur piece of information t was really usefull to beginner like me...